# how to use stored procedures in entity framework and use it mvc4 application

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I want to know how to use stored procedure which has 2 input parameters in entity framework and use those SP in MVC4 application step by step and plz dont share hard coded examples

Thanks&Regards
Maark

Answer (score 4):

This may help you,

**Call Stored Procedure using ExecuteStoreQuery function**

"ExecuteStoreQuery" should be used to query data. This method only works if T has a Default Constructor and also a Property name is the same as the returned column names. "T" can be any generic class or any data type and it might not be a part of an EF generated entity.

The following is the procedure to retrieve data using the "ExecuteStoreQuery" method from a Stored Procedure.

The method "T" can be anything, it may be an EF Generated entity or it may be a Custom Entity, so first I am creating a Custom Entity "EmployeeDetail". Here the EmployeeDetail properties name must be the same as the returned column of the select statement of the Stored Procedure.

// Creating Custom class to hold result of Stored Procedure

```
public class EmployeeDetail
{
    public int EmployeeID { get; set; }
    public string EmployeeName { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentName { get; set; }
}

// using Object Context (EF4.0)
var parameters = new SqlParameter[4] ;
            parameters[0] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "autoIds", Value = autoIds };
            parameters[1] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "inventoryType", Value = inventoryType };
            parameters[2] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "orderBy", Value = orderByStr };
            parameters[3] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "SqlString", Value = SQLString };


using (Entities context = new Entities())
{

        IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails  =  context.ExecuteStoreQuery<EmployeeDetails>    
                                                                                            ("exec GetEmployeeData @autoIds, @inventoryType, @orderBy, @SqlString", parameters).ToList();
}

// using DBContext (EF 4.1 and above)
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
        IEnumerable<EmployeeDetails> empDetails  =  context. Database.SqlQuery
                                                                      < EmployeeDetails >("exec GetEmployeeData ", null).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

My stored procedure that takes one parameter as input:

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[uspCopyApplicantForApply]
(
 @ApplicationId int 
)
as
begin 
    begin tran

    Declare @UserId int
    Select @UserId = ApplicantId from PostApplication where Id=@ApplicationId
    ---Copying Applicant Basic Data
    insert into Applicants(UserId,Title,FirstName,LastName,DOB,Phone,Mobile,Languages,MaritalStatus
                            ,MaidenName,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Country,VisaNumber,VisaType
                            ,IssueDate,ExpirtyDate,ValidFrom,VisaCountry,PassportNumber,Img,ApplicationId)
    Select UserId,Title,FirstName,LastName,DOB,Phone,Mobile,Languages,MaritalStatus
                            ,MaidenName,Address1,Address2,Address3,Address4,Country,VisaNumber,VisaType
                            ,IssueDate,ExpirtyDate,ValidFrom,VisaCountry,PassportNumber,Img,@ApplicationId
    from Applicants where UserId=@UserId and ApplicationId is null


    Insert into  Availability(StartTime,EndTime,Frequency,RecurrenceFreq,StartsOn,DoesNotEnd,EndsAfter,EndsAfterValue,EndsBy
                                ,EndsByDate,UserId,ApplicationId)
    select StartTime,EndTime,Frequency,RecurrenceFreq,StartsOn,DoesNotEnd,EndsAfter,EndsAfterValue,EndsBy
                                ,EndsByDate,UserId,@ApplicationId from Availability where  UserId=@UserId and  ApplicationId is null

    Insert into AppExperience(UserId,DateFrom,Title,DateTo,Employer,[Address],ApplicationId)
    select UserId,DateFrom,Title,DateTo,Employer,[Address],@ApplicationId 
    from AppExperience where   UserId=@UserId and  ApplicationId is null

    Insert into Competency(UserId,Title,StartDate,EndDate,ExpiryDate,Marks,Result,Notes,ApplicationId)
    select UserId,Title,StartDate,EndDate,ExpiryDate,Marks,Result,Notes,@ApplicationId
    from Competency where   UserId=@UserId and  ApplicationId is null

    Insert into [Resume](UserId,Title,[Path],IsDefault,UploadedAt,ApplicationId)
    select UserId,Title,[Path],IsDefault,UploadedAt,@ApplicationId 
    from [Resume] where   UserId=@UserId and  ApplicationId is null

    commit tran
    select 'Done'
end
```

Calling it from C# using Entity Framework:

```
InvovaDbContext db = new InvovaDbContext();

List<string> str = db.Database.SqlQuery<string>("exec uspCopyApplicantForApply {0}", postApplication.Id).ToList();
```

Comment: Hey hi Ehsan thanks for ur reply can u give me a step by step procedure as i m new for asp.net mvc thanks in advance

Comment: Its complete what I see you have yo dbcontext class??

Comment: hi actually i want complete step by step proceedure from importing a stored procedure to writing relevant code in models controllers and view i m a newbie to mvc understand

Answer (score 0):

It might help you

```
    DataSet dsDashboardInfoCompanyAdmin = new DataSet();
    #region Get TotalConnections(broken down by devices), TotalContracts, Total Connections(at last week) - for company admin

    SqlHelper helper = new SqlHelper();
    helper.OpenConnection();
    ArrayList sqlParameter = new ArrayList();
    sqlParameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@TenantID", TenantID));
    sqlParameter.Add(new SqlParameter("@CompanyID", CompanyID));
    dsDashboardInfoCompanyAdmin = helper.ExecuteDataSet("proc_DashboardInfoCompanyAdmin", sqlParameter);

    #endregion
```