# How to pass optional parameters to stored procedure using Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, stored-procedures, optional-parameters

I have the below stored procedure which returns 1000 rows.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[PROC_Insights_offinvoice_taxmaster]
@PROC_TYPE VARCHAR(50),@SEARCHBY VARCHAR(50) = NULL , @SEARCHVALUE     VARCHAR(250) = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @SQLQUERY VARCHAR(MAX)
    IF(@PROC_TYPE = 'DISPLAY')
    BEGIN

    SET @SQLQUERY = '
    SELECT  [taxUID],[taxCode],[formatUID],[formatName],[taxDescription],[classcode],[classDescription],[locationShortName],
            [zoneUID],[zoneName],[taxValue],[taxPercentage],[createdBy],[createdDate],[modifiedBy],[modifiedDate],[fy_Year]
    FROM [Insights].[dbo].[Insights_offinvoice_taxmaster]
    WHERE 1 = 1 '
    IF @SEARCHBY IS NOT NULL
    BEGIN
    SET @SQLQUERY  = @SQLQUERY  + 'AND '+ @SEARCHBY + ' like ' + '''' + '%' + @SEARCHVALUE + '%' + ''''
        END

        EXECUTE(@SQLQUERY)
    END

END
```

I have used the below method to call the stored procedure.

```
var context = new InsightsEntities();
var param = new SqlParameter[3];
param[0] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@PROC_TYPE", Value = "DISPLAY" };
param[1] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@SEARCHBY", Value = "TaxValue" };
param[2] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@SEARCHVALUE", Value = "1000" };

IEnumerable<Insights_offinvoice_taxmaster> tbl = context.Database.SqlQuery<Insights_offinvoice_taxmaster>("exec PROC_Insights_offinvoice_taxmaster @PROC_TYPE, @SEARCHBY, @SEARCHVALUE", param).ToList();
```

This one is working fine, when I pass all the three parameters. Suppose if I pass only the first parameter, it shows the error to pass the remaining two parameters. How to use optional parameters in entity framework?

Comment: Did you try looking at this? [how to use stored procedures in entity framework and use it mvc4 application](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23563405/how-to-use-stored-procedures-in-entity-framework-and-use-it-mvc4-application)

Comment: Yes. I tried. But I dont know how to pass the optional parameters. It has optional paramaters too.. How to pass in that case?

Comment: I'd say just pass `NULL` or empty strings and deal with them in your Stored Procedure?

Comment: Is there any other way to overcome this in front end?

Comment: Cannot comment on that, unfortunately. I've almost no c# experience. I'm always dealing with such things in SQL side, not in frontend.

Comment: @thevan: How about this - let say if you want to pass @SEARCHBY value null then you may try this `param[1] = new SqlParameter { ParameterName = "@SEARCHBY", Value = strSearchBy ?? string.Empty };`. Same way for other parameter.

Comment: can we negotiate the optional parameter?

Answer (score 0):

Is the error you're getting because you're missing a parameter or because you have an array of 3 items and some of them are remaining empty? When I have a SP with optional parameters, I just add what I need to send to a list and then convert the list to an array before the SP call.

```
var list = new List<SqlParameter>();
list.Add(new SqlParameter ( "@PROC_TYPE", "DISPLAY" ));

var param = list.ToArray();
```